# How to create a pointer without creating an object from inside a parameter list

Tags: c++, pointers, object, vector, containers

I need a vector of pointers to some preexisting objects, so I would like to create a pointer directly inside the vector.
I thought of calling the emplace_back function of my vector passing **new** as parameter, but this would not only create the pointer I want, but also an object. To get rid of this undesired collateral effect, I would do a **delete** pointer, which actually delete the object and leaves the pointer there, and then I would set this pointer to point to the preexisting object that I want. In code, it would be something similar to:

```
 std::vector myVector<ClassType*>;
 myVector.emplace_back(new ClassType());
 delete myVector.end();
 myVector.end()=&preexistingObject;
```

However, I think it's a waste to create an object just to delete it right after just because I want a pointer!

How can I create a pointer without creating an object in a way that I can create it from inside a parameter list (inside emplace_back in this case)?

I could write

```
ClassType *myPointer;
```

But the problem is that I cannot do it from inside emplace_back function as I need.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for your help,

Gustavo

Comment: First off, your posted code has no chance of compiling. Second, your plan is doomed. `myVector.end()` returns a value outside of the vector. `delete`ing and assigning to it is not recommended. `emplace_back` constructs for you. since all it's going to do is construct a pointer to `ClassType`, it doesn't do much for you. Use `push_back` for this job.

Comment: Thanks for the push back tip. And how can I create the pointer without creating an object from inside push back?

Comment: A pointer without a connected object is alway ```NULL``` - but this is also discouraged.

Comment: As I said, I will point to to the right pointee immediately  afterwards. So, this would not be a problem

Comment: The basics are a pointer can be made without it pointing anywhere or any object being created. By default a pointer doesn't point anywhere useful (or safe to use) until initialized. I don't know how your pre-existing objects are stored. That's why I haven't posted an answer. It could be as simple as `ClassType preexisting; myVector.push_back(&preexisting);` or `ClassType * preexisting = new ClassType(); myVector.push_back(preexisting);`, but the best I can do is guess.

Comment: Any reason why you are using pointers, by the way? `vector` is a great way to dump the memory management headache of pointers. You can probably use `emplace_back` or an initializer list to store the pre existing objects in the vector instead of whatever you are using and ditch the pointers completely.

Comment: The preexisting object is stored inside another vector, actually the end of the vector. I will try giving the address of this preexisting object as a parameter to push back

Comment: Ok! Giving the address worked :) thanks a lot! If you write your address tip as solution I will mark it as solved and you get the point :)

Comment: Ps: as you guessed, the preexisting objects are in their container by using emplace back already. The vector with pointers was used to loop over certain desired elements and perform activities based on how my preexisting objects inherit from other classes. Actually I made many different vector of pointers to the same preexisting, depending on which part of its the inheritance tree I want to perform certain tasks on

Comment: @ user4581301 : Using vector to store the preexisting objects is problematic because it changes address of its contents when getting to big. The solution was to use a list, as you can see in my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to pass the address of the pre-existing object to my container as  user4581301 suggested.

The only tricky point is that my software started crashing sometimes, and I have it tracked it to be a problem of pointers pointing to gargabe.

This happens because my pre-existing objects are stored inside a vector (std::vector), and when my vector got too big, all my pointers would get invalid, because... The vector changed the memory address of its contents when it has to make room for more items!

The solution is to store the pre-existing objects inside a list (std::list), which guarantess that my pre-existing objects won`t have their address changed when the list get too big.

To resume, in code, what I had to is:

```
std::list<PreExistingClass> myContainerOfObjects; //This HAS to be a list. Otherwise, dangling pointers!
std::vector<PreExistingClass*> myContainerOfPointerToObjects 

myContainerOfObjects.emplace_back(); 
myContainerOfPointerToObjects.emplace_back(&(myContainerOfObjects.back()));
```

Thanks!
Gustavo